# Export HTML to Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, export-to-excel

I try to export HTML table to Excel using JavaScript. Then I got this pop up before opening the Excel file:

> "The file you are trying to open, [file_name.xls] is in a different
>   format than specified by the file extension"

This is my code:

```js
var tableToExcel = (function () {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
         template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" ' +
            'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet> ' +
            '<x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets> ' +
            '</x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head> ' +
            '<body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
         base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) },
         format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function (table, name, filename) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }      
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
        a.download = filename + '.xls';
        a.click();
    }
})()
```

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/drafts/98280) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.